# Need help with starting RoR: Command "rails server" does not result in "Booting WEBrick"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, webrick

I need help to get started with RoR.

I currently follow this guideline:
http://allaboutruby.wordpress.com/2009/07/20/installing-rails-on-windows-3-years-later/#comment-11099

I followed step 1 through 3 w/o problems.

In step 5: I can get the webserver through WEBrick working.

When i put
    "rails server"
instead of getting "Booting Webrick", i get "rails new_path option"

thus when i try 127.0.0.1:3000 in the browser... it does work.

Can anyone guide me on this on how to get it up and runnning? (Im a total newb for now...so i need specific explanations! thanks!)

Comment: What about step 4? From the article: 'Type “rails hello” (in Rails 3 it should be “Rails new hello”) and it should output a bunch of lines “create app/controllers”, etc.' The message your getting is exactly what you get if you don't do that.

Comment: I did step 4 properly... the hello folder is in my \rails directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tutorial i can't see the command 'bundle install' - it's checking and installing all necessary gems in your system. So why you don't use another great rails tutorial - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are running windows, on which rails can be a little awkward.  You'll probably need to run the rails server command by pointing ruby at the server script.  On windows, your rails "commmand" is actually just a .bat file that lives in the /bin file of your ruby installation, and that .bat file just passes the arguments to ruby.  If you look at the rails gem that is installed on your machine, you'll see the files that correspond to the normal first argument of a rails command (console, generate, server, etc).  You might find it helpful to copy these to the /script directory of your application, and when you want to run a rails command you can just run "ruby script\server" from your application's main directory, though there may be more accepted ways of getting the same result.

Comment: Salut Marc. Thanks for the infos... I'll probably follow @megas tutorial. Since i'm a total noobs... it would be worth it to go through another full tutorial. (i've only done railsforzombies and read why's poignant guide so far...)